# How can I move data query away from user form. Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-access-layer

I'm completely new to C# programming and I'm trying to learn on my own. Currently I'm building a mini-project to exercise.

I understand that the user layer should not have any data query for security reasons perhaps?

So I have created a separate Data Access class to retrieve data. This is what my data access class looks like(I'll be using stored procedures for better security once I learn how to use it):

```
  public class DataAccess
{


    public List<Customer> FilteredCustomersList(string name)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("FineCreteDB")))
        {
            var output = connection.Query<Customer>($"SELECT * from `Customers` WHERE `Cust_Name` LIKE '{name}'").ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Basically I send over a string from the user form to query the database, the data is retrieved and stored in a list. User form:

```
 private void RetrieveData()
    {
        try
        {
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
            filteredcustomers = db.FilteredCustomersList(CustomerNameTxtBox_AutoComplete.Text);
            ntn_num = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_NTN).ElementAt(0);
            strn_num = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_STRN).ElementAt(0);
            address = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_Address).ElementAt(0);
            phone_num = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_Phone).ElementAt(0);
            id_num = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_ID).ElementAt(0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Customer not found. If customer was recently added, try updating DB.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
            filteredcustomers = db.AllCustomersList();
            ntn_num = "";
            strn_num = "";
            address = "";
            phone_num = "";
        }
    }
```

On the user form side, "filteredcustomers" holds the list of data sent back, now here is the **problem**: I use the filteredcustomers list to extract the different column values like so:

```
address = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_Address).ElementAt(0);
```

and then use them to populate the respective textboxes like:

```
Address_TxtBox.Text = address;
```

Everything works fine, but I don't want the userform to have these queries for all individual columns, because from what I've understood so far, this is bad programming and bad for security as well.

Can anyone guide me how I can keep the values in Data Access layer and just call them into my form?
I'm sorry if this is a long post, I'm just learning and wanted to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Is that *" how I can keep the values in Data Access layer and just call them into my form"* not what you're already doing with `Address_TxtBox.Text = filteredcustomers.Select(x => x.Cust_Address).ElementAt(0);` (which granted could be neater, i.e. `filteredCustomers[0].Cust_Address` - you don't need LINQ in there)?

Comment: I guess you're right, however when I use (x=>x.Cust_Address), doesnt that identify the column name in my SQL database? Or is that not a big deal?

Comment: Your real security concern should be SQL injection. Please use prepared statements. About separating data access and UI (which is because it makes the code easier to maintain) you want to have a data access facade that returns domain objects. `Customer` in this case. You seem to only want one customer, why don't you have a method that returns a populated `Costumer` instead of a `List<Customer>`? The column names matching is what is allowing MySQL to auto-populate, right? Well, don't auto populate, use names that make sense in your domain and write the code to populate those objects.

Comment: No, `x.Cust_Address` is the name of a property in a C# class in your program. Dapper created it from the name of the column in the database when it queried the database and created the class, but other than coincidentally sharing a name, it's nothing to do with the db any more - you called `.ToList()` on your connection, which ran the query and created a client side list of objects with various property names and values. DB is out of the equation now

Comment: @Theorat I'm under the impression that Dapper is being used here, though your point about parameters is quite pertinent as I don't think Dapper employs a "Interpret FormattableString and create parameterized query from it" facility like EFCore does

Comment: Oh, I thought Cust_Address is referring to the column in DB, thank you for the detailed clarification & ive also removed the LINQ- code is neater now.

Comment: @Theorat, Ive yet to learn prepared statements. I do have a method that returns the entire customer list, I use it to populate a data grid. while the filteredcustomers method is used to return data when searching for a particular customer.

Comment: So in short .Cust_Address is actually referring to the property in my Customer class and I can name the columns in my DB a bit differently. I am using Dapper not EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already doing everything reasonably correctly as per how Dapper is to be used. Dapper doesn't maintain a local graph of entities from the db, track changes to it and automatically save them. If you want that, use something like EF

For dapper you retrieve data with a SELECT and send it back with an UPDATE

If you're only expecting one Customer for the name, do this:

```
var output = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<Customer>($"SELECT * from `Customers` WHERE `Cust_Name` LIKE @n", new { n = name });
```

https://dapper-tutorial.net/queryfirst

This will return just one customer instance (or null; check it!) meaning you can tidy up your form code to:

```
        c = db.FilteredCustomer(CustomerNameTxtBox_AutoComplete.Text);
        ntn_num = c?.Cust_NTN;
        strn_num = c?.Cust_STRN;
```

And so on

Your "if customer was recently added try updating db" doesn't really make sense- the query is done live, so the db is about as up to date as it can be

Comment: Thank you, this query is much cleaner. About the "if customer was recently....", ill get rid of that.